# My DNS server appears to be correct but when I run online test they dont resond locally they answer and give valid response

Tags: dns-hosting, opensuse

```
dig @192.161.119.112 chucks-tees.com

; <<>> DiG 9.9.9-P1 <<>> @192.161.119.112 chucks-tees.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 32737
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 2, ADDITIONAL: 3

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;chucks-tees.com.               IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
chucks-tees.com.        172800  IN      A       192.161.119.112

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
chucks-tees.com.        172800  IN      NS      ns1.chucks-tees.com.
chucks-tees.com.        172800  IN      NS      ns2.chucks-tees.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns1.chucks-tees.com.    172800  IN      A       192.161.119.112
ns2.chucks-tees.com.    172800  IN      A       192.161.119.112

;; Query time: 1 msec
;; SERVER: 192.161.119.112#53(192.161.119.112)
;; WHEN: Sun Feb 12 12:04:34 EST 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 128
```

---

```
nslookup chucks-tees.com
Server:         209.159.189.8
Address:        209.159.189.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   chucks-tees.com
Address: 192.161.119.112
```

When I try to access it only works locally.

If I add the DNS to search, i.e. windows DNS to specify a server it works

Now to me it appears as it should work at this point I am waiting to see if it will propagate but not sure if this is working properly to respond to external queries.

Answer (score 1):

`192.161.119.112` only responds over TCP, not at all over UDP.

DNS is primarily used over UDP (but also TCP in certain scenarios), so this will be a significant issue.

Is there maybe some firewall in place that causes this? You'll want to make sure that both 53/udp and 53/tcp are reachable.

Comment: I have checked and edited the firewall file to make sure and I got this in response to test for upd port 53[+] Nmap scan report for 192.161.119.112
Host is up (0.100s latency).

PORT   STATE         SERVICE VERSION
53/udp open|filtered domain